# MySQL + NodeJS - Maintain AuditLog history in table when CUD operations performed on table

Tags: mysql, node.js, triggers

I want to store the audit log history in my mstAuditLog table.
Current solution I have implemented is, Wrote the trigger on table for CUD operations, but due to number of trigger increased the performance is lagging.
I search a lot and come to know that in .NET there is concept called "UnitOfWork". Can I implement the same in Node JS? If Yes then how can I implement it? Is there any npm available for it? please guide me on the same.